# upload file with cURL

Tags: mongodb, meteor, gridfs

Good morning,

I would like to know if there is a way to upload a file from my Desktop to Meteor Server in a GridFS Store.

These are the packages that I have installed to create the application:

```
accounts-base          1.1.3  A user account system
accounts-password      1.0.6  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui            1.1.4  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
autopublish            1.0.2  Publish the entire database to all clients
cfs:gridfs             0.0.31  GridFS storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:standard-packages  0.5.4  Filesystem for Meteor, collectionFS
ian:bootstrap-3        3.3.1  HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
insecure               1.0.2  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router            1.0.7  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform        1.2.1  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
nimble:restivus        0.6.2  Create authenticated REST APIs in Meteor 0.9.0+. Setup CRUD endpoints for Collections.
```

This is my single-file code:

```
var fileStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("fileStore");
Files = new FS.Collection("Files", {
  stores: [fileStore]
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.demo.helpers({
    files: function() {
      var objs = Files.find();
      return Files.find();
    }
  });

  Template.demo.events({
    'change #file': function(e, t) {
      var file = t.find('#file').files[0];
      console.log(file.name);
      var newFile = new FS.File(file);
      newFile.metadata = {
        fn: "filename" 
      };
      Files.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (!err) {
          var _fId = newFile._id;
          var _fn = file.name;
          var _collectionName = newFile.collectionName;
          var _basePath = "/cfs/files/";
          var _downloadPath = _basePath + _collectionName + "/" + _fId;

          FileList.insert({
            _id: _fId,
            fileName: _fn,
            collectionName: _collectionName,
            basePath: _basePath,
            downloadPath: _downloadPath
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Meteor.users.find({}).count() === 0) { 
      Accounts.createUser({
        email : "user@name.it",
        password : "password",
        profile  : {
          //publicly visible fields like firstname goes here
        }
      });
    }

    // code to run on server at startup
    console.log("Set Restivus");
    Restivus.configure({
      useAuth: true,
      prettyJson: true
    });

    Restivus.addCollection(FileList);

    Files.allow({
      insert: function(){
        return true;
      },
      update: function(){
        return true;
      },
      remove: function(){
        return true;
      },
      download: function(){
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I tried the command:

```
curl -v -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/cfs/files/Files/' -F 'file=@"download.jpeg";type=image/jpeg'
```

and this is the output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /cfs/files/Files/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 5626
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------955a67d5c4b2f2c4
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< access-control-allow-origin: http://meteor.local
< access-control-allow-methods: PUT
< access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
< date: Thu, 12 Mar 2015 14:25:55 GMT
< connection: keep-alive
< transfer-encoding: chunked
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

The command to read the file through cURL instead works:

```
curl -v -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/cfs/files/Files/d6DAowcAwZcXTKnJ5'
```

Could you please help me or provide an example?

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: As your error says: `access-control-allow-methods: PUT`. You can’t POST to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve had luck with the [Meteor Uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) package. It creates an upload endpoint that you can POST to.

Comment: I'll try asap and I will give you a feedback, thank you.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, with the following command curl -v -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload/' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' -T "file.txt" i get this error from the server "[Error: bad content-type header, unknown content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8]". Could you please help me?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the package to get it working normally (i.e. with an upload form in a Meteor template). Use that form to submit an upload, and look in the Network tab of your browser Developer Tools to inspect the Ajax POST request. Those are the headers you'll have to replicate in your curl request.

Comment: Have you some example? I tried with the method that you have suggest, but without success. Thank you.